# Counting of functions on a set of four elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Consider a set $B=\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\}$ and $f$ is a map from $B$ to $B$. Here $k$ composition of the function $f$ is defined as usual: $f^k(x)=f(f^{k-1}(x))$.

We are looking for functions $f$ such that for some $k$, $$f^k(x_i)=x_1$$ for all $i=1,2, 3,4$

How many such function $f$ exists?

Comment: Have you tried counting the number of such functions for specific values of $k$?

Comment: Here $k$ is eventual.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem statement. But you have 4 elements in your set. How big could $k$ possibly be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has the required property and let $G_f$ be the directed graph with vertices $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ and edge $a_i \to a_j$ whenever $f(a_i) = a_j$.  Each vertex of $G_f$ has outdegree 1. I make the following claims, all of which I think are simple:

1. $G_f$ must have at least one cycle, say $C$
2. $G_f$ must be connected, and it has only one component
3. The cycle $C$ is the only cycle in $G_f$, since every vertex must be in the same component as $a_1$.
4. The cycle $C$ is a *sink*: for each $x$, $f^k(x)$ is in $C$ for all sufficiently large $k$
5. $a_1\in C$.
6. No other vertex is in $C$.  For if $a_1 \ne f(a_1)$, then $f^k(a_1)\ne f^k(f(a_1))$ for every $k$.

So we have $a_1 = f(a_1)$.  There are now only 4 topologies for $G_f$, and we can easily enumerate them by considering how many elements have $f(x) = a_1$:

[image: $f(x)=a_1$ for all three $x$] Only one function looks like this.

[image] Six functions look like this.

[image] Six functions look like this.

[image] Three functions look like this.

The total is 16.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ has a cycle $a_0\mapsto a_1\mapsto \ldots\mapsto a_m=a_0$ with $m>1$ and we find $f^j(a_0)\ne f^j(a_1)$ for all $j$. Therefore, no such cycle exists and $f$ must have a fixpoint. This is necessarily $x_1$.

At least one of $x_2,x_3,x_4$ must map to $x_1$. There are $2^3-1$ choices for this,

- one where all map to $x_1$,
- three where two of them map to $x_1$; the remaining element must map to one of the other two.
- three where one of them, $x_i$ say, maps to $x_1$; at least one of the remaining two must map to $x_i$. Either both do, or we pick one and the other must map to the just picked.

In total this gives us
$$ 1\cdot 1 + 3\cdot2 + 3\cdot(1+2)=16.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously only one such function for $k=1$, namely $f(x_i)=x_1$ for all $i$.

There are 9 such functions for $k=2$. Let $\{a,b,c\}=\{2,3,4\}$ in any order, then the functions are the 6 functions defined by:
$$f(x_1)=f(x_a)=f(x_b)=x_1, f(x_c)=x_a$$
and the 3 functions defined by:
$$f(x_1)=f(x_a)=1, f(x_b)=f(x_c)=x_a$$

There are 6 such functions for $k=3$. Let $\{a,b,c\}=\{2,3,4\}$ in any order, then the functions are the 6 functions defined by:
$$f(x_1)=f(x_a)=1, f(x_b)=x_a, f(x_c)=x_b$$

There is no function with $k>3$.

You can prove this using graphs. :

Make a graph with 4 nodes representing the $x_i$. You need to add directed edges to represent the function: if $f(x_i)=x_j$ then there is an edge from node $x_i$ to node $x_j$.

- Prove that there can be no cycles (of two or more edges).
- Prove that $f(x_1)=x_1$.
- Enumerate all the 4-node tree graphs, with $x_1$ as a root, and count how many ways the other nodes can be labelled $x_2, x_3, x_4$.

Answer (score 0):

What about the permutations of four elements, shown as [cycles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html)?

```
(2 3 4 1), k=4
(2 4 1 3), k=4
(3 1 4 2), k=4
(3 4 2 1), k=4
(4 1 2 3), k=4
(4 3 1 2), k=4
```

The permutations either rotate to the left or to the right. Both directions can rotate by one, two or three. Therefore, six permutations exist.

Comment: It does not answer for all $i=1, 2, 3, 4$. For example, last permutation takes: 1 to 4, 2 to 3, 3 to 2. So 2 will not go to 1 for any $k$ since 2 and 3 are forming two cycle.

Comment: I first misread it as $f^k(x_i)=x_i$ as well, but it says $f^k(x_i)=x_1$.